# How to access type checkbox in css

Tags: html, css, input, checkbox, styling

In general what is the quality of your health?
                
                Outstanding

```
            <label for="q1">Good</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="q1" name="Question 1" value="...">

         
            <label for="q1">Bad</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="q1" name="Question 1" value="...">

         
            <label for="q1">Worse</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="q1" name="Question 1" value="...">
     

            <p class="q">How would you rate our concern for your privacy?</p>

            <label for="q2">Outstanding</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="q2" name="Question 2" value="...">

            <label for="q2">Good</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="q2" name="Question 2" value="...">
         
            <label for="q2">Adequate</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="q2" name="Question 2" value="...">
         
            <label for="q2">Need improvement</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="q2" name="Question 2" value="...">
         
            <label for="q2">Poor</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="q2" name="Question 2" value="...">
         
            <label for="q2">N/A</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="q2" name="Question 2" value="...">

           <p class="q">How often have you visited Medical center in past year?</p>

            <label for="q3">First Visit</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="q1" name ="Question 3" value="...">

            <label for="q3">2-5 Visits</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="q1" name ="Question 3" value="...">

            <label for="q3">More then 5 Visit</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="q1" name ="Question 3" value="...">

    </div>
```

I have read few posts regarding this topic here, but none worked for me.  I want to access the checkbox type for each question(q class) to style them in css to space out the options(checkboxes) across the width of the fieldset evenly, atm they are floating to the left.

TIA

Comment: your ids are not unique. Is it like that in your actual html also?

Answer (score 1):

Its not the actual checkboxes that need styling and incidentally its not even checkboxes you want here - its a single choice per quetion - so the correct element to use is an `input[type="radio"]` ... - you need to wrap each group in a wrapper (semantically a `fieldset` element) with the question as the `legend` element and use flex styling to apportion them out equally (`justify-content: space-evenly`) based on the label element wrappping both the input and the associated text..

Note that since each option has different number of options - each question / response group has different widths. I would recommend restructuring your questions to always have the same number of options so that it is a uniform layout.

I also moved the label text to after the radio input - this is more common and is imo better since the length of the lbel text is variable so the radio input is in different poisitions relative to the the label text. Putting it in front of the label text makes it be in a single location in each label. But thats just my thinking :)

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 0 16px;
}

legend {
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-bottom: 8px
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend class="q">In general what is the quality of your health?</legend>
  <label>
<input type="radio" id="q1" name="Question 1" value="good"/>
Good
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" id="q1" name="Question 1" value="bad"/>
   Bad
  </label>
  <label>
<input type="radio" id="q1" name="Question 1" value="worse" />
Worse
  </label>
</fieldset>
 
<fieldset>
  <legend class="q">How would you rate our concern for your privacy?</legend>
  <label>
<input type="radio"  name="Question2" value="outstanding"/>
Outstanding
  </label>
  <label>
<input type="radio" name="Question2" value="good"/>
Good
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="Question2" value="adequate"/>
   Adequate
  </label>
  <label>
<input type="radio"name="Question2" value="needImprovement" />
Need Improvement
  </label>
<label>
<input type="radio"name="Question2" value="poor" />
Poor
  </label>
<label>
<input type="radio"name="Question2" value="na" />
N/A
  </label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend class="q">How often have you visited Medical center in past year?</legend>
  <label>
<input type="radio"  name="Question3" value="firstVisit"/>
First Visit
  </label>
  <label>
<input type="radio" name="Question3" value="2to5"/>
2-5 Visits
  </label>
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="Question3" value="morethan5"/>
   More then 5 Visits
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
input[type='checkbox'] { ... }
```

see this [example](https://codepen.io/AbdlrahmanSaber2/pen/qBRKYeg)

Read [[this](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/blog/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/)][2](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/blog/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/) article it's very helpful

Comment: hey, thnx for responding, I've tried this, it doesn't work..

Comment: How? can you share your code style, see my updated answer, I shared the code with you, and also read the article it's very helpful